# What will be the sequence of inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

What will be the sequence of inheritance and what does the following code mean

```
class A
{
   int a;
   virtual void display()
   {
      cout<<"A";
   }
}
class B
{
   int b;
   virtual void displayB()
   {
      cout<<"B";
   }
}
class C:public B, virtual public B
{
}
```

Comment: did you mean `class C: public A, virtual public B` or is `class A` purely a distractor in this question?

Comment: **class C:public B, virtual public B**. This is really absurd, why would you do that ?? If you run it what happens.

Comment: And did you forget `class B: public A` or `class B: virtual public A`?

Comment: I think it's a typo, one of the base classes must be A.

Comment: What does it *mean*? It doesn't mean anything. Are you asking what purpose it serves or for a technical analysis of the structure? I don't mean to be flippant, but have you actually tried just compiling it and seeing what happens? You can learn a lot that way.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual inheritance means the class **shares** its base class **instance** with any other classes in the hierarchy of the instantiated object that inherit from it the same way (virtually).

Non-virtual inheritance means the class gets **its own instance** of the base class, regardless of any other classes that inherit from the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual inheritance avoids inheritance loops. For instance, this will issue a warning:

```
class A {
public:
    int count;
};

class B : public A {
};

class C : public B, public A {
};
```

Gives:

```
prog.cpp:9: warning: direct base ‘A’ inaccessible in ‘C’ due to ambiguity
```

Because for `C` the inheritance from `A` is ambiguous (it inherits directly from `A` but it also inherits from `A` through `B`).

This will compile without warnings:

```
class A {
public:
    int count;
};

class B : virtual public A {
};

class C : public B, virtual public A {
};
```

Because `C` has only one shared instance of `A`.

Comment: @Alex You're right, it just issues an ambiguity warning... (i'll edit my answer) But does it do what you expect? Isn't this an undefined behaviour?

Comment: No, it's not undefined behaviour. The problem with your answer is that although it's factually true now, the problem in the code is not the reason virtual inheritance exists. The problem is with accessing the direct base class `A`. But the solution is not to use virtual inheritance - that would be equivalent to just dropping `A` as a direct base class. The solution is to introduce an intermediate class (say, `AccessibleA`), make `A` it's parent, and inherit from it. I'm reversing my -1 but I can't give you a +1 for this answer.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for reversing and for the detailed explanation.
Why does virtual inheritance exists then?